# how can i Get proportional gray color?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, colors

here is some list i have:

```
      $gray-base:          #000 !default;
      $gray-darker:        lighten($gray-base, 13.5%) !default; // #222                    
      $gray:               lighten($gray-base, 46.7%) !default; // #777
      $gray-light:         lighten($gray-base, 65%) !default;   // #a6a6a6
      $gray-lighter:       lighten($gray-base, 93.5%) !default; // #eee
```

but i want to make #dddddd in proportional style as above other color are.how this can be done.thanks

Comment: Don't know how to do it but are you looking for those colors : `#3e3e3e`, `#dddddd`, `#e9e9e9`, `#fafafa`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$gray-medium:        lighten($gray-base, 86.5%) !default; // #dddddd
```

You can test it here: http://fiddlesalad.com/less/

HTML:

```
<div style="width:100px; height:100px;" class="grayMedium"></div>
```

LESS:

```
@gray-base:          #000;
@gray-medium:        lighten(@gray-base, 86.5%);

.grayMedium{
    background: @gray-medium;
}
```

In Source CSS window you should see:

```
.grayMedium {
    background: #dddddd;
}
```

Comment: no i am asking for to add  #dddddd this color to list as by making like this $gray medium : lighten(-----) that should be equal to #dddddd don't change base